# Committing save operations record by record inside threads in Django

Tags: python, django, transactions, python-multithreading

My goal is to make Django save records to DB record by record inside a thread. My code looks like this:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
       self.data = data 
       super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        for record in data:
           s = MySerializer(data=record)
           if s.is_valid():
               s.save() # I want this record to appear in db at once
```

I have `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` set to True inside `settings.py`. What I have tried to do is to include the `s.save()` command inside a transation like this:

```
if s.is_valid():
   with transaction.atomic:
        s.save()
```

But it did not help. I wonder whether this is possible and isn't it an anti-pattern ?

Comment: If it is transactional, you perform the save in the transaction, so only when the entire transaction is successful, you *commit* the transaction, and the changes are merged in the real database.

Comment: I want to commit it record by record, and I can't figure out the correct syntax and approach. That is, I want to validate the data and save it, and then see it in the real DB at once, then go on to validating and saving the next record, and so on...